# Jquery Disable another input field based on focus or change of current field in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a table which has input fields in table rows. For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="input1[1]" name="input1[1]" /></td><td><input type="text" id="input2[1]" name="input2[1]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="input1[2]" name="input1[2]" /></td><td><input type="text" id="input2[2]" name="input2[2]" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If we change or enter any value in input1, then it has to disable respective element of input2 of that row likewise if we enter any value in input2 it has to disable input1 elemnt of that row.

Can someone please help me in solving this. Thanks.

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers. Can we make this condition based so that the other field don't disable on certain values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would disable other inputs in the same row when a value is added to an input

```
$('td input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nR7j7/)

Comment: Great... it worked. Can we make it condition based. As I don't want the input field to disable on certain value in other field.

Comment: @SafiBaig incase for a set of values then have it in array like http://jsfiddle.net/nR7j7/2/

Comment: @adeneo Great it worked again :) . One last question, if we want to pass div id to the input fields, then how can we do that. As your solution disables all other input fields of that row.

Comment: @Praveen thanks for the reply. At some instances, your solution fails.

Comment: Got it working by giving respective class names. Thanks.